# Google analytics - last tracking causes previous tracking records to change

Tags: google-analytics

We set up enhanced ecommerce tracking for our shop where we among other things track **payment method** for each order. In our shop, as a customer, I completed two orders with **visa** payment option, which can be seen in GA:

[image]

Two orders created with visa option, all fine (don't mind the duplicate records for now).

But then I create a third order in our shop with **sofort banking** (just another payment option) and look how things change:

[image]

**All order payment methods were changed** to sofort banking. Of course I've tried hard reload to see if caching is not involved and even waited a day to see if it changes anything but no, the records stay with sofort banking.

Now we come to the second problem - the **duplication**. For some reason when I filter with *Secondary dimension: Checkout Options* (as can be seen on the pics) I get for each tracked order 2 records in the table. Those two problems might be somehow connected.

The question is: Does anyone have an experience with this and knows where the problem might be? If you need additional info please let me know, as of now I don't know in which direction to elaborate.

Comment: what does the datalayer look like when you pushed the transaction through for sofort banking?

Comment: @XTOTHEL well there is a huge amount of stuff, but regarding the payment method there is `dataLayer[0]` with default payment option inside and then once the user selects the payment method and goes to sofort, the chosen payment method is pushed to `dataLayer`. The tag is triggered once for the default payment method and for second time for the user-chosen payment method. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Is it possible that on the push for the third transaction, the datalayer values for the other two transactions are overwritten as well?

Comment: @XTOTHEL this is impossible, those transactions happened after each other with enough time between them. Moreover, as we don't have single page app, on each page the dataLayer gets reinitialized.

Comment: Can you use GTM or console to output the code for the datalayer that pertains to the ecommerce purchase? Also could you try not duplicating the transaction IDs?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186887/google-analytics-last-tracking-causes-previous-tracking-records-to-change

Comment: @XTOTHEL purchase and checkout json is in the chat